# Woocommerce Variant SKU

Tags: php, woocommerce, variants, sku

Currently in Woocommerce, when handling variable products, the SKU needs to be defined for each variant in full.

What I would like to do, is define a parent SKU, and then define suffix to SKU for each variant, and the final SKU is produced by concatenating the parent plus the variant suffix.

So lets say I have a parent product of base SKU `PRODUCT_0001`, the SKU `PRODUCT_0001` I would like to define here:

[image: BASE]

Then for variants, say `VARIANT_A`, I would like to define the suffixes here:

[image: VARIANT]

Now the final SKU for the variant of the product (ie what is transmitted during order workflow), I would like to represent as:

`PRODUCT_0001/VARIANT_A`

This way, this prevents double-handling of the same base product code when setting-up/defining many variants.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this on email, but this works on dashboard area and frontend..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sku', 'reigel_woocommerce_get_sku', 10, 2 );
function reigel_woocommerce_get_sku( $sku, $product ){
    // remove current filter to prevent unli loop on get_sku()
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); 
    if ( $product->get_type() === 'variation' ) {
        $parent = $product->parent->id?$product->parent->id:$product->get_parent();
        $sku = wc_get_product($parent)->get_sku() . '/' . $sku;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sku', 'reigel_woocommerce_get_sku', 10, 2 );
    return $sku;
}
```

disable sku uniqueness on variation...

```
add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', 'reigel_wc_product_has_unique_sku', 10, 3 );
function reigel_wc_product_has_unique_sku( $sku_found, $product_id, $sku ) {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    if ( $product->get_type() === 'variation' ) {
        $sku_found = false;
    }
    return $sku_found;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon, getting error "Product Variant SKU's Must be Unique". In the above case, the "Uniqueness" is achieved when the variant SKU is concatenated to the base SKU,

Comment: this is only for displaying it... checking for uniqueness is different story and might be impossible in your case unless you will enter the sku of the parent too...

Comment: Well the uniqueness check is conducted each time a new variant product is created, so the above is useless unless the uniqueness check can be suppressed or modified to check uniqueness on the value generated by: `wc_get_product($parent)->get_sku() . '/' . $sku;`

Comment: you can disable that function on variations level... I updated the code.. but this has very simple logic applied... you can expand it... example, check it's siblings if sku is found...